# PHP unlink function does not want to work

Tags: php, html

So I want to unlink a file using PHP, I send the file path to PHP through a link in HTML. When I echo the path it's correct, but when I use unlink it gives me these weird HTML tags inside the path aswell.

Heres my code:

```
<?php
    $fName = $_GET['name'];
    $fExt = '.epub';
    $fPath = $fName . $fExt;
    echo $fPath;
    unlink ($fPath);
?>
```

Heres the link:

```
echo '<a href="delete.php?name=ebooks/'.urlencode($name).'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">Delete</a>';
```

This is what the script outputs in the browser window:

ebooks/alice.epub

```
Warning: unlink(ebooks/

    <span class="title">alice</span><span class="author"></author>.epub): Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment\delete.php on line 6
```

Comment: I guess somebody should point out what an incredible blatant security hole this is...

Comment: "My, what an incredibly blatant security hole!"

Comment: Haha yea I am aware of that, for now I really just want to get a basic version of this working

Comment: Also, looks like the unlink parameter needs to be quoted.

Comment: @user1763722 That's not acceptable, IMO. 99% of the time the "basic version" that you get working is what gets shipped and used, and then exploited.

Comment: Use the post req instead..

Comment: This isn't for commercial purposes

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the solution is I just changed my unlink to this:

```
unlink (strip_tags($fPath));
```

Comment: The problem here is that your script is getting called with an argument that contains HTML tags for some reason. This isn't a solution; it's a workaround.